# Regex with capturing groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract file names from a long text.

- The filenames are all in a path
- The path is always prefixed with the text `Page source`
- They can appear anywhere on a line
- The text contains multiple lines
- All filenames end with `.html`

Given the following text:

```
Page source file:///somedir/subdir/subdir/mysource.html lorem ipsum more text
Lorem Ipsum ...
Lorem Ipsum Page source file:///anotherdir/sub/dir/anothersource.html
```

I want a list of all the file names:

```
mysource.html
anothersource.html
```

I've been trying to get it with the following regular expressions:

```
// this only gets the last one (because of the greedy .*)
Page source.*\/(.*\.html)

// This gets all occurrences, but the value in my capture group is the 
// complete path starting after the first occurrence of /
Page source.*?\/(.*?\.html)
```

How can I tell the regex engine to be non-greedy for the outside expression, but still greedy enough to go to the last `/` before the `.html` part?

Comment: I feel silly asking this of someone with so much more rep than me, but which regex engine are you using? What language are you working in?

Comment: The first seems ok: https://regex101.com/r/pJ4cH3/1 Can you describe more precisely the issue ?

Comment: I would say https://regex101.com/r/dH3vI5/1. That is, `(?:Page source).*\/(.*.html)`.

Comment: @Antwane and fedorqui Thanks for the input. My sample text wasn't really in line with my real text so somehow on my actual text it isn't working. Can't really put my finger on it.

Answer (score 7):

```
Page source.*?([^\/]+?\.html)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uX6fY2/2